# url in hyperref with local destination?

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, urls

Using the `hyperref`package in the `xelatex`environment, the external `url="..."` generated lead to a local address. With  `doi="..."` it's not a problem at all. Any ideas how to solve this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}     
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\usepackage{polyglossia}  % Sprachumschaltung
\setdefaultlanguage{german}% Voreingestellte Dokumentsprache: Deutsch

\usepackage[babel,german=guillemets]{csquotes}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{literatur.bib}

@misc{Hohn.2013,
 author = "Höhn, Hans-Joachim",
 title = "Theologie als Wissenschaft",
 subtitle = "Theorie welcher Praxis?",
 url = "www.podcasts.uni-freiburg.de/religion-und-theologie/theologie/dies_academicus/10634363",
 urldate = "2014-11-25"
}

@incollection{Keller.2009,
 author = "Keller, Reiner",
 title = "Das interpretative Paradigma",
 doi = "10.1007/978-3-531-91454-1_2"
}

\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[
   bibencoding=utf8,
   style=verbose-inote,
   language=ngerman,   
   backend=biber]
{biblatex}

\bibliography{literatur.bib}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\cite{Hohn.2013}
\cite{Keller.2009}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The outcome looks right, but the url of `Hohn.2013` is wrong:
[image]

Comment: Your URL should start with `http://`, so that `biblatex` knows its HTTP and not FTP or HTTPS.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about an error in the input: The link was not given in the correct format.

Comment: @moewe I disagree.  While the answer is trivial, the question/error is not.  Most of the questions on this site boil down to 'there was an error in the input'.  Would you mind making your comment an answer?

Comment: @SeanAllred You are probably right, I have added an answer. You are definitely right about the error in the input, my point was that it was a rather small one.

Comment: Interestingly when I played around with the example I found that my software automatically added the `http://` prefix in the link (not in the visible output though). I use `hyperref v6.83m`, `biblatex` `2.9a` (Biber 1.9) on a general up-to-date MikTeX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you help `biblatex` and `hyperref` figure out which protocol (HTTP, HTTPS, FTP, ...) to use, you should be fine.

DOIs appear correctly since `biblatex` turns the raw `doi` into the proper hyperlink itself.

So the obvious solution is to always specify the protocol properly as in

```
@misc{Hohn.2013,
 author   = {Höhn, Hans-Joachim},
 title    = {Theologie als Wissenschaft},
 subtitle = {Theorie welcher Praxis?},
 url      = {http://www.podcasts.uni-freiburg.de/religion-und-theologie/theologie/dies_academicus/10634363},
 urldate = {2014-11-25},
}
```